# R: use index of a list with the apply and rep commands

Tags: r, list, indexing

Here is a list

```
ll <- list(3L, 5L, 2L)
```

and the output I'd like should be as below

```
1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3
```

So far I have tried the `rep()` command, but I'm missing how to "index" the list.

```
unlist(lapply(ll, function(x) rep(x, x)))
```

What is the solution or alternative approach?

Edit:
It has to work inside the apply function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
> rep(1:3, ll)
[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3
```

to address the OP comment:

```
> unlist(lapply(seq_along(ll), function(x) rep(x, ll[[x]])))
[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3
```

Comment: I would generalize this to `rep(seq_along(ll), unlist(ll))`.

Comment: @AnandaMahto, I considered that but ended up abstaining for the sake of simplicity, but yes, that is the more general solution.